# Going from LDraw/LeoCAD to Physical Set

Tags: building, moc, ldraw

Once I've designed a MOC using either LDraw or LeoCAD where can I go to get the bricks I need to then build that set in the real world?

I've been poking around forums for an hour now trying to get to the answer and I must be missing something.

Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is a silly question.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to BricksSE!  No question is silly (Maybe duplicitous), but never silly.

1. Go to *[Bricklink.com](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/wanted/upload.page)*
2. Create an Account.
3. Go to "Want" drop down menu.
4. Click "Wanted List".
5. Look for the blue box that says "+ Created Wanted List".
6. **Important:** Create and give the new list a meaningful name other than
   "default" or all future uploads will be merged into one list named "default" (*very annoying*).
7. Go back to the "Want" drop down menu and click on "upload". You'll get the screeny below.
8. Find your build's file location.  Make sure your file is a compatible upload type.
9. Click, Hold, Drag, and Drop your file onto the upload screen.
10. Upload your pieces to the meaningful Wanted List name you've created.

The site fills in the magic of getting you connected to the people who'd like to sell you your parts.

[image]

Note the condition of each part after you upload can be ***new***, ***used*** or ***any***.

If you're buying ***Tiles***, always buy them new.  Scratched *Tiles* always look bad.

For any type of brick, always buy these colors new too:  White, Yellow, Blue, Light gray.  They tend to also make your final build look... worn if bought mixed or used.

Comment: As an additional note the designer produced by BrickLink (Stud.IO) has really very good integration into the BrickLink marketplace and makes it really easy to see prices on parts while in the software so you can tweak your design to better match availability and/or price targets.

Comment: @Nathan Stohlmann - Good point!

Comment: this was very thorough and efficient.
Thank you all!!
Now my living room must prepare for the coming storm...

Answer (score 2):

In case you have all your sets as well as additional/spare bricks added to [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/) you can upload your digital model file and identify just the bricks you are missing. Custom list can be created in the following place:
Main page > My LEGO > My Custom lists

Once you upload the file you can use "Build this List" feature. And then "Buy parts". This would give you options from Bricklink as well as Brickowl.